# (Re)formatting PHP code in Vim

Tags: php, vim, code-formatting, macvim

How do I format PHP code that looks like this

```
class SomeClass
{
    function insideclass()
    {


    }
}
```

into this, using Vim without any external tool?

```
class SomeClass {
    function insideclass() {


    }
}
```

I am not arguing that this is the best way to format the code, but this is what we are following in the team.

**Edit**: Removed reference to the snippet addon, which caused some confusion about the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two unrelated problems and you won't find a unique solution to both.

1. **You don't like the default `class` snippet.**

   No problem. If it's not already there, create `~/.vim/snippets/php.snippets` and customize it to fit your team's rules by following the other answers. Snipmate is not smart enough to adapt itself to your coding style.
2. **Some of your existing code doesn't conform to your coding rules.**

   Snipmate won't help at all since it only deals with *insertion*, not *transformation*. You are going to need either some external [beautifier](http://beautifyphp.sourceforge.net/) or a few macros.

   ***EDIT***

   Here is a very simple command that does exactly what you want *on your example*. I offer no guarantee that it's going to work for everything everywhere. Take it as a naive starting point.

   ```
   :g/^\s*{\s*$/normal kJ
   ```

   - `:g/pattern` acts on all lines containing `pattern`, see `:h :global`.
   - `^\s*{\s*$` matches all single `{` whatever the amount of whitespace between them and the beginning of the line.
   - `normal` executes `normal` commands, see `:h :normal`.
   - `kJ` goes up one line and `J`oins this line with the matched line.
   - Done.

   ***ENDEDIT***

Comment: Actually my question was more towards the second problem. I just snipate addon as an example. My bad. I have edited the question now to clarify it.

Comment: Apart from using beautifier, is there any Vim based solution for the second problem?

Comment: No turn-key solution I'm aware of. Maybe someone has written a script based on PHP_Beautifier? I don't know. It looks like a typical use-case for macros and substitutions.

Comment: +1. I knew that `kJ` was the simplest solution but dint know how to execute it on finding a match. Thanks!

Comment: Wow!! this was exactly what I was looking for. Simple and elegant. I am going to map it to easy to remember key in my .vimrc.

Answer (score 2):

Why not modify the source code of that addon?

For example, change these:

```
snippet class
    /**
     * ${1}
     */
    class ${2:ClassName}
    {
        ${3}
        function ${4:__construct}(${5:argument})
        {
            ${6:// code...}
        }
    }
```

to

```
snippet class
    /**
     * ${1}
     */
    class ${2:ClassName}{
        ${3}
        function ${4:__construct}(${5:argument}){
            ${6:// code...}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah modifying the addon is definitely an option. I am just trying to see if it possible to convert code from one style to other in general.

Answer (score 0):

Al the snipmate snippets are stored in a directory. Go to that directory and edit the file you want.

The direcorty is stored in the vim directory and called `snippets`. In there you see a `php.snippets` file. Go to that file and on line 70 you can edit the snippet for the class.