# PHP automated coding standards fixer for non-hanging braces?

Tags: php, coding-style, standards, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any free cmd-line scripts which can re-format PHP source-code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785287/are-there-any-free-cmd-line-scripts-which-can-re-format-php-source-code)

I've been evaluating several coding standards fixers to run on our code. This is to perform some auto-fixing on legacy code which uses deprecated things like perl-style comments.

The most useful fixer I have used so far is php-tidy which is found here: http://phptidy.berlios.de/

This tries to conform to the PEAR standard, which is almost exactly what I need, except that I want non-hanging braces for control structures.

Can anyone point me a (linux-based) command-line tool that can apply a fixer to use the ANSI style of braces?:

```
function nice_brace()
{
    if (isset($nicebrace))
    {
        // I like non-hanging braces
    }
}
```

Rather than the PEAR/Zend style:

```
function ugly_brace() {
    if (isset($ugly_brace)) {
        // I find this code harder to read
    }
}
```

Edit: For others looking for something similar, check this script out: https://raw.github.com/gist/366837/25713637b6f2f9e1ec63abf3233142765df4b931/phpbb-reformat.pl

Many thanks

Comment: get an ide that lets you do this like zend studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following command in Vim to fix it

```
:g/^\s*{\s*$/normal kJ
```

More details from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118738/reformatting-php-code-in-vim)

Comment: I never thought of using vim to accomplish this. It is nearly what I want, only I want it the other way around. I will experiment with this and try and find a solution, Thanks!

Comment: `:%s/^\(\s*\).*\zs{\s*$/\r\1{/` This does what I want in vim. However, this is a bit too manual. I would prefer a cli tool so that I can automate the fixer via my Jenkins server. The tool doesn't have to be PHP-specfic

Comment: I had a brain wave that instead of using vim, I could just use some good old fashioned awk and sed

Comment: Indeed. Put it in a shell file, and there you got your CLI tool.